# Data type during transferring data with ADF to Databricks tables converts into string

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, databricks, azure-databricks

Big Picture:
Netezza Tables (with integer values, with datatime values) -----> Databricks table with columns in string

- I am transferring large tables from Netezza to ADLS and then from ADLS to Databricks (again using ADF = Azure Data Factory)
- Loading data directly data from Netezza to Databricks is put aside due to different architectural decisions.
- In Netezza there are tables with integer, datatime values in them, which I want to make them available as is to the Databricks

Details:

- ADF has a generic pipeline with parameters which makes it able to read all Netezza tables
- ADF has lets say a daily pipeline where generical pipeline is duplicated to cover all netezza tables
- The above architecture for ADF will cause an issue which down the line everything is ingested as string. and I am not able to change via map tabs in ADF
- ADF is writing data in ADLS as CSV
- Down the line of ADF pipline, I am running a databricks notebook which load data into databricks table, and I can see all columns in string

I have an idea as following but it is not working

```
dataSchema = StructType([
                         StructField("col1", IntegerType()),
                         StructField("col2", LongType()),
                         StructField("col3", FloatType()),
                         StructField("col4", DoubleType()),
                         StructField("col5", StringType()),
                         StructField("col6", DateType()),
                         StructField("col7", TimeType()),
                         StructField("col8", ArrayType()),
                         StructField("col9", MapType()),
                        ])
df.write \
  .option("schema",dataSchema)
  ......
  .save()
```

Please help with you experience, on how I can enforce these table columns to desire data type

Comment: what data format is used for exported data? CSV? JSON?

Comment: Hi @AlexOtt, data is sitting in ADLS as CSV

Comment: @AliSaberi You can use `Parquet` format instead of csv to write to ADLS.  That will retain the equivalent data type of the Netezza table instead of string for all columns. I am using the same pipeline(netezza -> ADLS) in production, and works fine with parquet format. If you still want to proceed with your solution, please update whats the error you see with the spark code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `parquet` format instead of CSV in the sink for the ADF pipeline. It will retain the datatype as in source, rather than string for all columns like in CSV. Also, `parquet` is good for you in couple of ways:

1. You can also use some form of compression like snappy, to save some space in ADLS
2. Easy with spark/databricks/Hive integration, as you mentioned in your qn.

A small comparison for you to understand. I tried with parquet and csv, and you can see the difference here.
**ADF pipeline sink:**
[image]

**CSV sink** (All columns as string)
[image]

**Parquet: ( Columns with equivalent format)**
[image]

Comment: @Ali Saberi Please upvote answer, if it helped you. Thanks!

Comment: Done, Thanks for great help